# How to use files with .save extension

Tags: linux, nano

I have my Laravel site running on apache2 server. Also I use php 7.1, git, composer and sometimes I use nano to change files on the server. In `app/Http/Controllers/` I found file `UploadsController.php.save` which is similar to `UploadsController.php` but have some changes. Could somebody explain how I should use this file and how it has been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.save` files are recovery files that Nano creates when its buffer is dumped. If your `Uploadsontroller.php` file looks OK, you can just delete `Uploadsontroller.php.save`.

You should also probably add `*.save` to your `gitignore` file so these files don't clatter up your `git status` results.